# Order by multiple custom field values in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field called "sale_status" and the values ("For Sale", "Sold", "Let") are displayed in a radio button in admin. Now each of them can be assigned to a single property.

Currently the query fetches the properties order by post date but I want it to be by sale_status and then date.

My code is as below--

```
 $args = array(
      'post_type'       => 'zoo-property',
      'posts_per_page'  => $query__per_page, 
      'post_status'     => 'publish',
      'paged'           => $query__page,            
      'meta_key'        => 'sale_status',
      'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
      'order'           => 'DESC',

      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $query__types,
        $query__locations,
        $query__statuses,
        $query__investments,
        $query__price
      )

    );


    $properties_wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    echo "Last SQL-Query: {$properties_wp_query->request}";
```

But it not showing in correct order.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to include multiple sort criterion in the same query the `orderby` value must be an array. See [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for details. Try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'zoo-property',
    'posts_per_page'  => $query__per_page, 
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'paged'           => $query__page,            
    'meta_key'        => 'sale_status',
    'orderby'         => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'post_date' => 'DESC' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $query__types,
        $query__locations,
        $query__statuses,
        $query__investments,
        $query__price
    )
);
```

Comment: You can use `'meta_value_num meta_value_num'` as well. The array is needed only if you want to set a different sort order for each ordered field (this functionality [was added in WP 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)).

Comment: @Technoh Many thanks for your help. It worked like a charm. Just wondering if it is possible to show the all "For Sale" first and then all "Sold" and then all "Let"